# How to avoid nested chains of "if let"?

Tags: rust, refactoring, readability

I'm wading through a codebase full of code like this:

```rust
if let Some(i) = func1() {
    if let Some(j) = func2(i) {
        if let Some(k) = func3(j) {
            if let Some(result) = func4(k) {
                // Do something with result
            } else {
                println!("func 4 returned None");
            }
        } else {
            println!("func 3 returned None");
        }
    } else {
        println!("func 2 returned None");
    }
} else {
    println!("func 1 returned None");
}
```

That's a stupid, simplified example, but the general pattern is that:

- There are a bunch of different functions which return an `Option`.
- All the functions must be called in sequence, with the return value of the previous function (if it's not `None`) passed to the next function.
- If *all* functions return a `Some`, then the final returned is used for something.
- If *any* returns `None`, then execution stops and some kind of error is logged - usually an error message that informs the user exactly which function returned `None`.

The problem, of course, is that the above code is an ugly and unreadable. It gets even uglier when you substitute `i`, `func1` etc. with variable/function names that actually mean something in the real code, and many examples in my real codebase have far more than four nested `if let`s. It's an example of the [arrow anti-pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrowAntiPattern), it completely fails the [squint test](https://atom.io/packages/squint-test), and it's confusing how the error messages appear in reverse order to the functions which can cause them.

Is there really not a better way to do this? I want to refactor the above into something that has a cleaner, flatter structure where everything appears in a sensible order. [if let chaining](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2497-if-let-chains.html) might help but it doesn't look like that feature is available in Rust yet. I thought maybe I could clean things up by using `?` and/or extracting some helper functions, but I couldn't get it to work and I'd rather not extract a ton of new functions all over the place if I can avoid it.

Here's the best I could come up with:

```rust
let i : u64;
let j : u64;
let k : u64;
let result : u64;

if let Some(_i) = func1() {
    i = _i;
} else {
   println!("func 1 returned None");
   return;
}
if let Some(_j) = func2(i) {
    j = _j;
} else {
   println!("func 2 returned None");
   return;
}
if let Some(_k) = func3(j) {
    k = _k;
} else {
   println!("func 3 returned None");
   return;
}
if let Some(_result) = func3(k) {
    result = _result;
} else {
   println!("func 4 returned None");
   return;
}


// Do something with result
```

But this still feels very long and verbose, and I don't like how I'm introducing these extra variables `_i`, `_j` etc.

Is there something I'm not seeing here? What's the simplest and cleanest way to write what I want to write?

Comment: I think the main reason `if let` is used is for error checking, which I'd have reformulated the question to, how can I do early returns on errors using inverse `if let` syntax?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [let-else statements](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/3137-let-else.md), a [feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87335) which was added to stable rust in [version 1.65](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/11/03/Rust-1.65.0.html).

> ###### RFC 3137
>
> Introduce a new `let PATTERN: TYPE = EXPRESSION else DIVERGING_BLOCK;` construct (informally called a **let-else statement**), the counterpart of if-let expressions.
>
> If the pattern match from the assigned expression succeeds, its bindings are introduced into the surrounding scope. If it does not succeed, it must diverge (return `!`, e.g. return or break).

With this feature you can write:

```
let Some(i) = func1() else {
    println!("func 1 returned None");
    return;
};
let Some(j) = func2(i) else {
    println!("func 2 returned None");
    return;
};
let Some(k) = func3(j) else {
    println!("func 3 returned None");
    return;
};
let Some(result) = func3(k) else {
    println!("func 4 returned None");
    return;
};
```

---

If you wanted to try it on an older version of rust, you would have to enable the unstable feature:

```
#![feature(let_else)]
```

Comment: FWIW there's a [crate which does that as a macro](https://crates.io/crates/guard). The syntax is basically the same, except enclosed in a `guard!()`, and it needs a final semicolon.

Comment: This is now stable as of 1.65

Answer (score 15):

If-let chaining will make this a lot nicer, but for now (assuming you don't want to use nightly), it's possible a slight refactor could help. For example, pulling all but the last call of the chain into its own function allows you to use the `?` operator:

```rust
fn get_result() -> Option<u64> {
  let i = func1()?;
  let j = func2(i)?;
  let k = func3(j)?;
  func3(k)
}

fn main() {
  if let Some(result) = get_result() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

If you need more fine-grained control over the error cases, you could return a `Result` instead:

```rust
enum Error {
  Func1,
  Func2,
  Func3,
  Func4,
}

fn get_result() -> Result<i64, Error> {
  let i = func1().ok_or(Error::Func1)?;
  let j = func2(i).ok_or(Error::Func2)?;
  let k = func3(j).ok_or(Error::Func3)?;
  func4(k).ok_or(Error::Func4)
}

fn main() {
  use Error::*;
  match get_result() {
    Ok(result) => {},
    Err(Func1) => {},
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to put two more things on your list of "eventually look into" things: The simple `Option::and_then`:

```rust
let result = func1().and_then(func2).and_then(func3).and_then(func4);
match result {
  Some(result) => …,
  None => …,
}
```

And the slightly more tricky, but incredibly convenient `anyhow::Context`:

```rust
use anyhow::Context;
let j = func2(i).context("Func2 failed")?;
```

Answer (score 4):

A slightly better version of the `if let ... else { return }` can be used:

```rust
let i = if let Some(i) = func1() { i } else {
   println!("func 1 returned None");
   return;
};
let j = if let Some(j) = func2(i) { j } else {
   println!("func 2 returned None");
   return;
};
let k = if let Some(k) = func3(j) { k } else {
   println!("func 3 returned None");
   return;
};
let result = if let Some(result) = func3(k) { result } else {
   println!("func 4 returned None");
   return;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I can achieve this without needing to extract a new function? I can see how extracting a new function will often make things cleaner, but sometimes it would be easier if I don't have to, especially if there aren't many `if`s required. Do I have a choice?

Comment: @GMA Not really, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue and the solution of @Caesar helped me a lot.

I would add in my case I need the results of all the functions involved, and I've modified that code to achieve that in this way:

```rust
let Some((first, Some(second)) = a.func().and_then(|first| Some((first, b.func(second))) {
    result += c.func(first, second);
}
```

The down side is it could end up by having a lot of nested `Some` for long chains, but in my case I only have two levels and this solution seems to be quite efficient.

PS: `cargo clippy` suggested to use `map` instead of `and_then`, which is indeed shorter and cleaner in this case :)